# I'm getting error Ambiguity between '¨Form1.score' and ¨Form1.score'

Tags: c#

i have int score = 0; under public partial class Form1 : Form  and Im getting error in txtscore.Text = "Score: " + **score**; and **score** = 0; in private void RestartHry() does someone know why is that? Or know how to fix that bsc i have no idea. ......................................................................................................................................................................................

```
namespace Projekt_Havlík
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool vpravo, vlevo;
        int rychlost = 8;
        int score = 0;
        int minul = 0;

        Random rndX = new Random();
        Random rndY = new Random();

        PictureBox minulcoin = new PictureBox();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RestartHry();
        }

        private void MainGameTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //naprogramovaní textboxů
            txtscore.Text = "Score: " + score;
            txtminul.Text = "Minul: " + minul;

            //změnění postavy při jízdě do leva/prava
            if (vlevo == true && player.Left > 0)
            {
                player.Left -= 12;
                player.Image = Properties.Resources.main_left;
            }
            if (vpravo == true && player.Left + player.Width <this.ClientSize.Width)
            {
                player.Left += 12;
                player.Image = Properties.Resources.main_right;
            }

        }

        private void KeyIsUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                vlevo = false;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                vpravo = false;
            }
        }

        private void KeyIsDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                vlevo = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                vpravo = true;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void RestartHry()
        {

            foreach(Control x in this.Controls)
            {
                if (x is PictureBox &&(string)x.Tag == "coins")
                {
                    x.Top = rndY.Next(80, 300) * -1;
                    x.Left = rndX.Next(5, this.ClientSize.Width - x.Width);
                }
            }

            player.Left = this.ClientSize.Width / 2;
            player.Image = Properties.Resources.main_right;

            score = 0;
            minul = 0;
            rychlost = 8;

            vpravo = false;
            vlevo = false;
            CasovacHry.Start();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: score is defines as : int score = 0;  So you are trying to write to a textbox and need to use 
ToString() to convert the number to text.

Comment: @jdweng I already tried it and it doesnt work

Comment: @jdweng The line is `txtscore.Text = "Score: " + score;` - I would have expected this to automatically do `ToString` when concating it _to_ a string?

Comment: fildor is correct the Net will automatically convert when you combine a string with a number.  So it looks like you have on the form a textbox called "score" and a variable called "score".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the name of your "score" variable, try calling it like, "myScore", typically if something is ambiguous it is because there are two fields or properties with the same name in assembly references that are not directly specified in the code.